# Wrong Number of Arguments in Initialize (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby

I am following along with a tutorial at:

http://neurogami.com/content/neurogami-10_minutes_to_your_first_Ruby_app/#sidebar4

I have checked and rechecked the code, and I do not understand why ruby is not reading my variable `app_map` as a valid argument.

I have searched online for similar questions, and they exist, yet I can not understand why this variable is not working. I also am not exactly sure what `initialize` means, as I am an absolute beginner with Ruby. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Launcher

  def initialize (app_map)
   @app_map = app_map
  end

  #execute the given file using the associate app
  def run file_name
    application = select_app file_name
    system "#{application} #{file_name}"
  end

  #given a file, lookup the matching application
  def select_app file_name
    ftype = file_type file_name
    @app_map[ ftype ]
  end

  #return the part of the file name string after the last '.'
  def file_type file_name
    File.extname( file_name ).gsub( /^\./, '' ).downcase
  end

end

launcher = Launcher.new

end
```

I am not sure what this code is supposed to run, but I have multiple error messages.

```
tinyapp.rb:8:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1) (ArgumentError)
    from tinyapp.rb:30:in `new'
    from tinyapp.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5):

In this line, you are instantiating a `Launcher`:

```
launcher = Launcher.new
```

That will call the `initialize` method on it. That method expects an argument:

```
def initialize (app_map)
  @app_map = app_map
end
```

In order to resolve the error, you will need to pass in a parameter for the `app_map` argument. I don't know what it's supposed to actually be here, but that'll look something like this:

```
launcher = Launcher.new(the_app_map)
```